# Travel from Indonesia to India via Bangkok(DMK)

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, airports, bangkok

I will be reaching DMK by Indonesia Air Asia and have a connecting flight to India in Thai Air Asia. Layover is 9 hrs.

Please help me out if I will need a transit visa in Thailand.

PS: I have an Indian passport. I do not intend to leave Bangkok airport and my tickets were purchased under one booking number.